# Why is there no 'hadoop fs -head' shell command?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

A fast method for inspecting files on HDFS is to use [tail](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#tail):

```
~$ hadoop fs -tail /path/to/file
```

This displays the last kilobyte of data in the file, which is extremely helpful. However, the opposite command `head` does not appear to be part of the shell command collections. I find this very surprising.

My hypothesis is that since HDFS is built for very fast streaming reads on very large files, there is some access-oriented issue that affects `head`. This makes me hesitant to do things to access the head. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Lack of community interest to implement such feature? [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-206](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-206).

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I would say it's more to do with efficiency - a head can easily be replicated by piping the output of a hadoop fs -cat through the linux head command.

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file | head
```

This is efficient as head will close out the underlying stream after the desired number of lines have been output

Using tail in this manner would be considerably less efficient - as you'd have to stream over the entire file (all HDFS blocks) to find the final x number of lines.

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file | tail
```

The hadoop fs -tail command as you note works on the last kilobyte - hadoop can efficiently find the last block and skip to the position of the final kilobyte, then stream the output. Piping via tail can't easily do this.

Comment: How to put this head hadoop thing into alias form. argpas() {
     
        hdfs dfs -cat $1 | head -$2
}
alias hh=argpas
I have tried this but it is not working

Comment: bash function to call the same (optionally via `-n {num} {hdfs_path}` giving num lines to show): `hdfs-head() { [ "$1" = "-n" ] && { n=$2; shift 2; } || n=10; hdfs dfs -cat "$@" | head -n $n ; } `

Answer (score 9):

Starting with version 3.1.0 we now have it:

> Usage: hadoop fs -head URI
>
> Displays first kilobyte of the file to stdout.

See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-206).

Answer (score 3):

```
hdfs -dfs /path | head
```

is a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: How would you save the result of this | head -n into a file in HDFS?

Comment: @Loebre `hdfs dfs -cat /file |head -1 | hdfs dfs -put - /otherfile` where the dash before `/otherfile` refers to `STDIN`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the folowing command

```
hadoop fs -cat /path | head -n
```

where `-n` can be replace with number of records to view

Answer (score 2):

In Hadoop v2:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /file/path|head
```

In Hadoop v1 and v3:

```
hadoop fs -cat /file/path|head
```