# How to copy first few lines of a large file in hadoop to a new file?

Tags: hadoop

I have one big file in hdfs bigfile.txt. I want to copy the first 100 lines of it into a new file on hdfs. I tried the following command:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/billk/bigfile.txt |head -100 /home/billk/sample.txt
```

It gave me a "cat: unable to write output stream" error. I am on hadoop 1.

Are there other ways to do this? (note: copying 1st 100 line to local or another file on hdfs is OK)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this -

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/billk/bigfile.txt | head -100 | hadoop -put - /home/billk/sample.txt
```

I believe the "cat: unable to write output stream" is just because **head** closed the stream after it read its limit. see this answer about **head** for hdfs - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779388/3438870

Comment: to copy the sample to local, use this:
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfsfile | head -100 | hadoop fs -get path/to/local/sample1

Comment: If you want the results local you can just redirect it to a file rather than piping through hdfs 
hadoop fs -cat /user/billk/bigfile.txt | head -100 > local/sample.txt

Comment: @Scott this also results in the `cat: unable to write to output stream` problem

Comment: @conner.xyz The question was how to write the first 100 lines of a file in HDFS to a new file in HDFS.  You are correct I believe it still throws the `cat: ...` error because head stops the output stream before the file stream is finished but it will write the 100 lines to the new HDFS file still.

Comment: You can always add `2>/dev/null` to skip error message  `hdfs dfs -cat /user/billk/bigfile.txt 2>/dev/null | ...other code after pipe...`