# hadoop fs -text file returns "text: Unable to write to output stream."

Tags: hadoop

I have some files on the HDFS, and I try to use command

```
hadoop fs -text filename | head -10
```

after exec the command, it always returns the first 10 lines to the terminal, and it's what I want, but it always returns a line "text: Unable to write to output stream." attached to it, I feel very confused about what the attached line means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to read a compressed file. Anyhow `head` closed the stream after it read its limit hence, hadoop throw'ed a warning saying "text: Unable to write to output stream." because `head` has already closed the stream to which hadoop's `text` is trying to write to.

Take a look at this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778137/why-is-there-no-hadoop-fs-head-fs-shell-command/19779388#19779388) as well.

Comment: so it means that the "text" command is trying to open the whole file and write all lines to the output stream, but the "head" command will just close the output stream when the limit lines are written to the output stream, so the "text" command just have no output stream to write the reset of the data, which causes this warnings, am I right?